# How to avoid exception on using filtering types for nullable properties

Tags: graphql, hotchocolate

Using Hotchocolate when you try to use filtering via custom filtering type and add to filtering property with nullable type it throwsa an exception on schema generation phase (EffectiveDate is DateTime?):

```
descriptor
     .BindFieldsExplicitly()
     .Filter(x => x.EffectiveDate);
```

This issue is currently open on Hotchocolate repository - https://github.com/ChilliCream/hotchocolate/issues/1034

But are there any workarounds to use filtering by nullable properties?

Comment: We will release a fix next week for this with version 10.2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug is fixed, closed and released in 10.2. Since the current stable version is even greater than 10.2 you just need to update your libs to fix the issue.